# Error while installing Postfix 2.9 on Freebsd 8.2 (cyrus-sasl)

Tags: postfix, freebsd

Trying  to install postfix from ports and get this error:

```
===>   Compressing manual pages for cyrus-sasl-2.1.26_2
===>   Running ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig -m /usr/local/lib
===>   Registering installation for cyrus-sasl-2.1.26_2
===>   Returning to build of postfix-2.9.4_2,1
Error: shared library "sasl2.2" does not exist
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/mail/postfix.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/mail/postfix.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/mail/postfix.
```

```
ldconfig -r | grep sasl
[/usr/ports/mail/postfix] [12:49] [pts/0] 
    111:-lsasl2.3 => /usr/local/lib/libsasl2.so.3
    297:-lsasldb.2 => /usr/local/lib/compat/pkg/libsasldb.so.2
    312:-lsasl2.2 => /usr/local/lib/compat/pkg/libsasl2.so.2
    318:-lsasldb.3 => /usr/local/lib/compat/pkg/libsasldb.so.3
```

Comment: ...and ? Did you *want* to build postfix with Cyrus SASL support ?

Comment: Yes, i want to build it with Cyrus SASL support.

Comment: As the above result clearly shows, postfix expects cyrus-sasl >= 2.2; you have installed **2.1**.

Comment: Ok, so how can i install postfix 2.9 via FreeBSD ports? Or it is a port bug? I also trie to install postfix 2.8 (from ports) and got the same error.

Comment: Also i tried postfix 2.6 and 2.7 and got the same error

Comment: Actualy Cyrus SASL 2.2 does not exist http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/

Comment: looking for solution too, i am getting same error with FBSD9.1 and PF2.9

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have run `portsnap fetch update` before. Afterwards upgrade the ports which are not up to date anymore by using `pkg_version -l "<"`.

This should solve your issue.